# Rails/Postgres How to query hstore value if it contains value of passed array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, hstore

I'm using Postgres with hstore in my Rails project. I store address information (street, city, postcode, country,...) in an hstore column called "address". I can query the database for a certain city like this:

```
Company.where("address -> 'country' = 'Finland'")
```

Works perfectly.

What I would like to do is querying the database for an array of countries like this:

```
Company.where("address -> 'country' IN my_array_of_many_countries")
```

Of course it's not working that way. Does anyone know how I can get all Companies from countries stored in my my_array_of_many_countries array?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to transform you array into a string:

```
my_array_of_many_countries = ['France', 'Germany']
my_array_of_many_countries_string = "'#{my_array_of_many_countries.join("','")}'"
Company.where("address -> 'country' IN (#{my_array_of_many_countries_string})")
```

This would only work if your array only contain strings.
Btw, Haven't tested it.

Comment: My array contains only strings. I tried it out and it works all fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that someone use string interpolation with SQL in 2015 without properly escaping everything?

Comment: @muistooshort As you can see from the example, `my_array_of_many_countries` can not be injected in any way, since it is created locally, not received from parameters or something, so, yes i am.

Comment: It is still a terrible idea when there are better ways to do it that won't break when a country name contains an apostrophe.

Comment: I'm gratefull for both answers. MurifoX helped me getting this part of the app running right away. Considering further development, I chose to go for mu is too short's answer. If the countries will be passed from outside the app some day, I'm safer that way. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord knows what to do with Ruby arrays so let it do its job:

```
Company.where("address -> 'country' IN (?)", my_array_of_many_countries)
```

Please don't use string interpolation for building SQL unless you really do need to do it that way and you're meticulous about properly escaping and quoting everything.